# php - json_decode undefined index, but the value is there

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am very puzzled.

I passed an key value pair object from jquery to php. and alert it back out again successfully but if I go to the php page. it says the data is null or undefined index.

below is my jquery

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   var obj= {
                'key': 'value',
            };
$.ajax({
                url: "../folder/file.php",
                type: "POST", 
                data: {
                    'obj' : obj
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
});
```

below is my php

```
$data = $_POST['obj']; // this is line 1
echo json_encode($data); // this is line 2
```

With the above code, when I click test button, I will get alert `value`. but if I go to the php page after I clikced the test button. the page says `Notice: Undefined index: obj on line 1, and null on line 2.`

Why?

I am getting alerted the value I put in. So it must mean the data went through and back. but the php page says it is null.

Comment: The reported behavior seems doubtful: `$_POST['myobj']` will behave consistently as an expression; it will either evaluate to a string or result in an 'undefined index'.

Comment: you already said `$data = $_POST['myobj'];` works, just use the same path you used that worked

Comment: may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/3385827

Answer (score 2):

`$_POST['myobj'];` is an array, not a json string.

While it is a JS object when you use it as the value of `data` in your ajax method, it is translated into post data unless you explicitly set `contentType`. By default the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Because you are using the default content type:

`$_POST['myobj']['key1']` should be the value of key1 for example.

Use `var_dump` on the object to see it better, and understand the structure of it.

i.e.

```
var_dump($_POST['myobj']);
```

Comment: hmm var_dump($_POST['myobj']) says null. and $_POST['myobj']['key1'] both didnt work.  if I change echo json_encode($data); to just echo. I was alerted object Object. I think it has something to do with this

Comment: Try just `var_dump($_POST)` now. There is literally no logical reason why `$data = $_POST['myobj']; echo json_encode($data);` would work like you suggested but replacing that code with what I put above would not.

Comment: Unless you're saying that jQuery is returning the alert with `null` in it, which makes sense, since you explicitly set `dataType` to `json`. If that's what you're saying, then remove the dataType from json so that you can see the data being dumped.

Comment: if I dont echo json_encode. I either get no alert or an object Object alert. var_dump($_POST) gets array(0) { }.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you post JSON objects to PHP you can read them via [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input). `php://input` contains the raw POST data and therefore is a string that need to be JSON encoded:

```
// Read all
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// String -> array (note that removing `true` will make it object)
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
// Print it
var_dump($obj);
```

Small demo (test.php)

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

// Read all
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// String -> array (note that removing `true` will make it object)
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
// Print it
var_dump($obj);
?>
```

Output using `curl` to call it:

```
$ curl -X POST -d '{"test": "value"}' localhost/test.php
array(0) {
}
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

Finally, if you want to be able to pass JSON data and URL parameters at the same time, use the following:

```
function buildRequest(){

    // Get Data
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // Form the request from the imput
    if ($json!=""){
        $_REQUEST = array_merge_recursive($_REQUEST,json_decode($json, true));
    }
}

buildRequest();
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Calling the above with both URL and data parameters results in:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"test": "value"}' localhost/test.php?param=value2
array(2) {
  ["param"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
  ["test"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

Let me know if the above works for you.